# connection time out to a postgress running on docker

Tags: laravel, postgresql, docker, postgresql-9.3

i have a project running on docker using laravel and postgres .
in my project every thing is fine and project is up without problem ,
but when i want to connect to database which is on a container using navicat or phpstorm it gives me this error :

```
could not connect to server : connection timed out . is the server running on host "172.18.0.4" and accepting tcp/ip connections on post 5432 ??
```

my project is connecting without problem with this details :

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=project_database_1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=project
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=123456
```

and here is my docker compose file :

```
version: '3'
services:

  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php/Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network


  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

  #db
  database:
    image: "postgres" # use latest official postgres version
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/ # persist data even
    networks:
      - app-network



  #redis
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ../data/redis:/data
    entrypoint: redis-server --appendonly yes
    restart: always
    networks:
      - app-network




#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

#Docker Volumes
volumes:
  database-data:
    driver: local
```

any idea what can be wrong that i cant connect to database ??

Comment: how are you connecting to database in PHPStorm? Can you attach the screenshot as well. I'm able to connect successfully in DataGrip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - pgsql
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network


  #db
  pgsql:
    image: "postgres" # use latest official postgres version
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/ # persist data even
    networks:
      - app-network
```

Try this. With `depends_on` you are saying app should depends on pgsql. First pgsql comes up then your app comes up when you enter `docker-compose up`

Comment: thanks but it says docker-composer file is not valid

Comment: Oh, i used wrong syntax i fixed it. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on